# how to use @queuebinding with @rabbitlistener?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Seems since spring-amqp version 1.5, there is a new annotation @queuebinding。But how to use it, i don't know if it can be used on a class or a method? Does it exist any example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure what problem you have, but here is a sample exactly from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven):

```
@Component
public class MyService {

  @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
        value = @Queue(value = "myQueue", durable = "true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value = "auto.exch"),
        key = "orderRoutingKey")
  )
  public void processOrder(String data) {
    ...
  }
```

And yes, it can be use as on class level as well as on method level.

Comment: I am seeking help on a similar concept, but not sure If i am allowed to post my question here? @Artem Bilan, based on your response may I ask a question

Comment: Just raise a new SO thread and we will try to help you

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan, this is the link to my actual thread so I just expanded on my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484183/can-my-selenium-framework-consume-an-incoming-message