# Can my selenium framework consume an incoming message

Tags: java, selenium, jsp, rabbitmq, message-queue

I would like to know how my Selenium framework can dequeue a message sitting in a message queue. I have built an application to send a JSON string containing k/v pairs to a message queue.

My architecture is as follows and separate apps:

1. A JSP Web Application exists accepting parameters resulting in a JSON string
2. A message sender exists and takes the JSON string and publishes it to a Queue
3. A message consumer exists and consumes the Messages. Its basically just sitting here
4. A Selenium Java Framework exists, but I would like to process the messages and for each message it will interpret the k/v pairs and kicks off the script.

I would like to use the messages already in the queue and process these messages within the selenium framework, how can I achieve this?

I will appreciate the help. I have edited the question with the code

> This is the code snippet to send the JSON Message

```
public class MessageSender {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    SingleNumberLogin generateLogin = new SingleNumberLogin();
    //function call to build the JSON object
    String jsonQueue = generateLogin.buildJASONObject();

    ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    try {
        Connection connInterface =  conFactory.newConnection();
        Channel mqChannel = connInterface.createChannel();
        mqChannel.queueDeclare("MyQueue",false,false,false,null);
        //Just assigning json to another string, then publish the message      
        String myMessage = jsonQueue;

        mqChannel.basicPublish("","MyQueue",false ,false, null,myMessage.getBytes());
    }catch (
            IOException | TimeoutException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
    conFactory.setUsername("guest");
    conFactory.setPassword("guest");
    conFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
    conFactory.setHost("localhost");
    conFactory.setPort(5672);
}
```

}

> code snippet for  consumer code that I have inserted into the startup function of the automation script, so if a message arrives a single test case is executed

```
    @BeforeTest
public static void initializeTestBaseSetup() throws Exception, IOException, TimeoutException {
    ConnectionFactory conFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    Connection connInterface =  conFactory.newConnection();
    Channel mqChannel = connInterface.createChannel();
    mqChannel.queueDeclare("MyQueue",false,false,false,null);
    mqChannel.basicConsume("MyQueue", true, (consumerTag, message) -> {
        //convert to byte array
        String m = new String (message.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Message received" + m);
    }, consumerTag -> {

    });
}
```

> Output JSON
>
> ```
> JSON Message received 2020-08-28T20:39:30.845{
> ```

```
  "NUMBER": "0000011111",
  "Type": "BAU",
  "User": "MyUser ",
  "Email": "riidonesh@gmail.com",
}
```

When tested in isolation, it works perfectly fine, what I mean is that I send the message and check that the consumer receives it, adding the consumer code to my framework is where i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't think about what you have as a "*selenium* framework" - think of it as a "*java* framework".

Selenium is a set of libraries that allow you automate the web browser at a GUI level. The framework is the coded solution to facilitate creation and management of your test suite - it doesn't have to be limited to selenium and chances that's already just one of its components.

Trying to answer your question directly:

- SELENIUM cannot read messages
- JAVA can read messages

If your rabbitmq has a web front end then you *may* be able to use selenium for it, but this isn't a very efficient or a logical solution.

What you might want to consider, and what i would do, is extending your framework to use the rabbitmq libraries to process messages as you need. These libraries are designed for this task.

You say:

> I would like to process the messages and for each message it will
> interpret the k/v pairs and kicks off the script.

I understand this to mean that the messages are the pre-req data for the tests. If you want to read the values of a message before the test you can either:

- Place the get/read in a generic `@Before` method
- or if it's a specific message per test case, add it into the start of the test.

You're working in java so you can do whatever you want really.

To get you started, the rabbitmq tutorial [starts here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html).

This is there hello world example for reading messages from the queue:

```
public class Recv {

  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response,I have built it and yes my MessageSender is invoked via a JSP web-front.The reason for this is that users will now access the web-front and send data in the form of a JSON string to MessageConsumer which sits between the JSP web-front and automation test suite / Framework, this framework will in-turn log into main Web App to validate the data, execute the test case (A single test case in this scenario).  JSP Web-front => MessageSender => MessageConsumer =>  Framework?

Comment: I have done some research on this and also visited some existing posts. I am unable to yet find a solution. I have added the code for the consumer in a @Before method. Now App A (Web App with MessageSender), App B (the consumer withing the Java framework). Yet unable to trigger the script based on the incoming message.

Comment: Hi @Riidonesh - how can i help? - As it stands, I have no idea what's in your messages, what your code looks like, what you're trying to run and what else you've tried so far.... all i can suggest for now is start small: don't worry about it being the the before - create a simple unit test that can connect, authorise and read message from the queue. Confirm you're getting the data you expect. Then figure out how you're going to pass that into a test - there are ways to do this but a comment block on here won't cut it...

Comment: I appreciate it @RichEdwards, I have added some code above. The consumer code is now part of the code in my framework which i have added to a startup function. I am not sure how I should listen for incoming messages.